# How does android parse the xml layout file and display the view in Graphical Layout.

Tags: android-layout, xml-parsing, android

How does android parse the xml layout file and display the view in Graphical Layout.

1. What parser does android use internally?
2. How is the parsing so quick and efficient?

I know there are some similar questions on SO but I wanted to know specifically about above which I could not find. In case these questions do exist a link to them would be great. :)